# Por que a teoria dos conjuntos é tão importante para a computação?

Tags: matemática, característica-linguagem, teoria-da-computação

Para a teoria da computação, linguagens formais entre outras áreas assim como para a programação (desenvolvimento) a teoria dos conjuntos sempre está presente, sei que a matemática está fortemente ligada a computação, mas por que se tem uma ênfase tão grande em conjuntos?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

É que algumas das verdades matemáticas que afetam os conjuntos também afetam a computação.

Por exemplo, pode-se provar que cada programa de computador pode ser relacionado a um número inteiro. Basta imaginar todos os bits de um aplicativo como um único número inteiro, bem grande. Portanto, o conjunto de programas existentes é semelhante ao conjunto dos números inteiros (eles têm a mesma "cardinalidade").

Já os problemas computacionais podem ser relacionados ao conjunto dos números reais. Este conjunto possui uma cardinalidade maior que o dos inteiros, ou seja, podemos dizer que há muito mais números reais que inteiros, apesar de se tratarem de dois conjuntos infinitos.

Desta conclusão a respeito dos conjuntos, concluímos que existem muito mais problemas computacionais do que programas de computador. Dizendo de outra forma, há inúmeros problemas computacionais que não têm solução, não podem ser resolvidos por um programa de computador.

Um desses problemas é justamente o "problema da parada", onde um programa deve analisar outro e decidir se o mesmo vai executar por um tempo finito, ou não. Resolver este problema seria muito útil porque tornaria possível a um ambiente de desenvolvimento "provar" automaticamente que um programa está livre de bugs, etc.

Mas infelizmente o problema da parada não tem solução. É claro, os analisadores estáticos conseguem pegar alguns bugs e concluir que **alguns** programas vão parar ou não. O que é impossível é achar um algoritmo genérico, universal, capaz de analisar qualquer outro programa inclusive ele mesmo.

Então aí está um exemplo da importância da teoria dos conjuntos. Por causa dela sabemos que existem alguns limites no que um computador pode fazer, o que poupa o trabalho de ficar tentando :)

Comment: Uma adição: A teoria dos conjuntos é a base para criação de programas de análise, Os desenvolvedores utilizam a teoria dos conjuntos para instruções de repetição e variação entre os processos e atividades desenvolvidas na execução do programa.

Answer (score 10):

Além do contexto exposto pelo colega @epx, creio ser importante mencionar que a teoria dos conjuntos é base para o Modelo Relacional, implementado amplamente pelas engines de banco de dados relacionais.

Mais detalhadamente, o Modelo Relacional é baseado na Álgebra Relacional. Disciplinas sérias de bancos de dados não introduzem nenhuma tecnologia (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, SQLite) ou mesmo SQL, sem antes expor o aluno à Álgebra Relacional.

As operações da Álgebra Relacional são a Projeção (colunas selecionadas no SELECT), Seleção (aquilo que se coloca na cláusula WHERE), Produto (um cross-join, também conhecido por produto cartesiano), Junção (um INNER JOIN), União (operador UNION e UNION ALL), Diferença (operador MINUS e EXCEPT em alguns bancos de dados).

Mais detalhes:

[Modelo Relacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_relacional)

[Álgebra Relacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_relacional)

Comment: É, eu tinha incluído isso na resposta, mas como entendo muito pouco desse negócio, preferi deixar de fora. Mas de um ponto de vista prático é um uso importante mesmo. É muito mais provável um desenvolvedor topar com um banco de dados do que com um problema impossível :)

Answer (score -2):

Pitagoras já dizia tudo pode ser representado por um número, o que completamente difente de dizer que tudo é um numero.
No limite os numeros são 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 o resto são pseudo abstração de baixo nivel que a maquina consegue lidar muito bem, já as palavras complicam um pouco mais o pessoal da janela complica mais ainda, e ai você analise os marcadores texto(alguem viu alguma caneta por ai?) são o cúmulo é como o colega afirmou tudo pode ser represetado por numero logo fica muito fácil entender isso.
Como, C e o mestre Dennis Ritche criou o mundo ele sabia o que estava fazendo.